# How do I delegate to a member property in Swift?

Tags: swift, delegates, delegation

I have a class that should expose a few methods and properties from one if its members. Right now, I have code like:

```
class Parent {
  private let child: Child

  var name: String {
    get { return child.name }
    set { child.name = newValue }
  }
}
```

Is there a more concise way to write this?

Comment: Looks really simple and concise as it is now. I don't think there is anything you could do to improve it.